# Accessing objects/variables inside of a for loop

Tags: java, loops, variables, object, for-loop

Is there a way to access the object "rec" after the for loop when I try to print out rec.report()?

(Report() is a method inside of the class BmiRecord that returns new calculated results).

```
for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
     int height = scanner.nextInt();
     int weight = scanner.nextInt();
     String name = scanner.nextLine();

     BmiRecord rec = new BmiRecord(name, height, weight);
} 

    System.out.println(rec.report());
```

Comment: Because of `scope`. https://www.google.com/search?q=java+scope&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=java+variable+scope   The workaround is to define the object `BmiRecord rec = null` outside for `for` loop, then only assign it inside the loop. Then you can use it after the loop terminates

Comment: Rec is defined inside the loop. So it no long exists outside.

Comment: Each thing has a scope and it is not visible outside that. In this case the for loop has a scope delimited by curly braces

Comment: Either do what @Kon wrote, or create a collection like 'List<BmiRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();' and then add the records to it: 'records.add(rec);'. Later you can iterate over that list (examples can be found on Google or Stackoverflow) to print each entry.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the object **rec** outside the for loop because the scope of the object is only valid in the for loop. As you have created that object inside the for loop.

You can relate this with another question. Why can't you access the local variable defined inside a function in another function?

Refer the following code:

```
BmiRecord rec[]=new BmiRecord[limit];

for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
 int height = scanner.nextInt();
 int weight = scanner.nextInt();
 String name = scanner.nextLine();

 rec[i] = new BmiRecord(name, height, weight);
} 
for(BmiRecord re:rec){
     System.out.println(re.report);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the object "rec"?

Comment: An array is not wrong, but using a Collection instead is almost always the better decision. Just a note, no need to update your answer :).

Comment: You are right. However, OP seems to be new to the language that's why I skipped the Collection part.

Answer (score 1):

Because `rec` is a private variable defined within the `for` loop. To access outside of it's scope you need to define it before the `for` loop. Here is your new code:

```
BmiRecord rec;

for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
 int height = scanner.nextInt();
 int weight = scanner.nextInt();
 String name = scanner.nextLine();

 rec = new BmiRecord(name, height, weight);
} 

System.out.println(rec.report());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing object outside of loop which is out of scope, try something like this

```
    BmiRecord rec = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        int weight = scanner.nextInt();
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        rec = new BmiRecord(name, height, weight);
    }

    System.out.println(rec.report());
```